# How to calculate percentage?

Tags: sql, sql-server, percentage

Given below is the database table(TableA).

```
SlNo  TeamName  WorkInfo 
----  -------   -------  
1     Team1        0    
2     Team1        0    
3     Team1        1     
4     Team2        1    
5     Team2        1 
6     Team2        1      
7     Team3        0      
8     Team3        1
```

I have two text boxes for selecting start and end date. I want to display details in between that dates.

Given below query is giving the details and count based on the start date and end date.

```
SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
       Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 FROM tableA 
WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) GROUP BY TeamName
```

The above query shows the out put like given below:

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0
--------   -----    ------
Team1        1        2
Team2        3        0
Team3        1        1
```

I want to display the percentage based on the `greatest count` in `Count1` and `Count0` . Help me to modify the above solution. `The expecting output sample is given below:`

Here  in `Count1` 3 is the greates value.Based on that I have to find the percentage of Count1 values. And in `Count0` 2 is the greatest value.Based on that I have to find the percentage of Count0 values.

Expecting Out Put :

```
TeamName   Count1   Count0  Percentage1  Percentage0
--------   -----    ------  -----------  -----------
Team1        1        2        33.33%         100%
Team2        3        0        100%           0%
Team3        1        1        33.33%         50%
```

Help me to find a proper solution. Thank You.

Comment: where is your code ? could you add your existing function for getting the percent values?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare @maxcount1 float
declare @maxcount0 float

select @maxcount1 = max(count1), @maxcount0 = max(count0)
from 
(SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
 Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 FROM tableA 
 WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) GROUP BY TeamName) as s

select teamname, count1, count0, 
round((cast((count1 * 100) as float)/@maxcount1),2) as percentage1,
round((cast((count0 * 100) as float)/@maxcount0),2) as percentage0
from 
(SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
 Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 FROM tableA 
 WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) GROUP BY TeamName) as s
```

Note that you should try to do the formatting such as adding % sign at UI level, so that the percentage column can remain as a number rather than as text. Also, you might want to store the results of your initial query in a table variable, and then read from it, rather than including the entire query in a subquery.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/NWLB32509)

Answer (score 2):

**SAMPLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP(TeamName VARCHAR(20),Count1 NUMERIC(10,2),Count0 NUMERIC(10,2)) 

INSERT INTO #TEMP
SELECT 'Team1' , 1 ,2 
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Team2', 3,0
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Team3', 1,1
```

Use PARTITION BY to get the the Maximum value and compute the percentage calculation on that

**QUERY**

```
 SELECT *
,CAST(CAST(Count1 * 100 /CAST((MAX(Count1) OVER())AS NUMERIC(4,2)) AS NUMERIC(38,2)) AS VARCHAR(6))+'%' PERCENTAGE1
,CAST(CAST(Count0 * 100 /CAST((MAX(Count0) OVER())AS NUMERIC(4,2)) AS NUMERIC(38,2)) AS VARCHAR(6))+'%' PERCENTAGE0
FROM TEMP
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to calculate percentage from your query, you can use the below code

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TeamName,Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 1 THEN SlNo end) AS Count1 , 
           Count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN WorkInfo = 0 THEN SlNo end) AS Count0 FROM tableA 
    WHERE (SubmitDate BETWEEN @start AND @end) GROUP BY TeamName 
)
SELECT *
,CAST(CAST(Count1 * 100 /CAST((MAX(Count1) OVER())AS NUMERIC(4,2)) AS NUMERIC(38,2)) AS VARCHAR(6))+'%' PERCENTAGE1
,CAST(CAST(Count0 * 100 /CAST((MAX(Count0) OVER())AS NUMERIC(4,2)) AS NUMERIC(38,2)) AS VARCHAR(6))+'%' PERCENTAGE0
FROM CTE
```

- **See the working query [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1d5df/1)**

Answer (score 0):

Your `SELECT` statement should have the structure

```
SELECT Count_Expr, Count2_EXPR, PCT_EXPR, PCT2_EXPR FROM ...
```

a percentage calculation is always

```
Num * 100.0 / Total
```